# Provider: How to notify listeners of A from B

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have two controllers using the changenotifiers in my app and I want to notify listeners of A from B. I have be trying two different methods for the same.

**Method 1**

(Controller A):

```
class DrawController extends ChangeNotifier {

   void clearCanvas() {
   selectedText = '';
   shouldClearCanvas = true;
   currentDrawPoints.initialPoint = null;
   currentDrawPoints.endPoint = null;
   print(currentDrawPoints.initialPoint);
   notifyListeners();
   }
}
```

Calling it from (Controller B):

```
class GameController extends ChangeNotifier {

  DrawController drawController = DrawController();

  void someFunction(){

     drawController.clearCanvas();
     notifyListeners();

   }

}
```

**The above method doesn't work.** It does execute the function and changes the value but it does not change the UI (does not rebuild the widget).

**Method 2:**

(Controller A):

```
class DrawController extends ChangeNotifier {

   void clearCanvas() {
   selectedText = '';
   shouldClearCanvas = true;
   currentDrawPoints.initialPoint = null;
   currentDrawPoints.endPoint = null;
   print(currentDrawPoints.initialPoint);
   notifyListeners();
   }
}
```

Calling it from (Controller B):

```
class GameController extends ChangeNotifier {

  DrawController drawController = DrawController();

  void someFunction(BuildContext context){

     Provider.of<DrawController>(context, listen: false).clearCanvas();

   }

}
```

This second method works and it updates the UI too but I think this is the wrong method of doing it.

As using it after async await gives the warning "Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps."

```
  class GameController extends ChangeNotifier {

  DrawController drawController = DrawController();

  void someFunction(BuildContext context) async {

     User? userData = await localStorage.getUserData();   

     Provider.of<DrawController>(context, listen: false)
      .clearCanvas(); //Gives warning "Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps."

   }

}
```

Can anyone tell me the correct way of doing it.

Comment: It seems right to me...

Comment: Second method? But using it after async await gives the warning "Do not use BuildContexts across async gaps."

Comment: can you use a setter function in Provider A to run the clearCanvas() function?

Comment: How can I do that in above case?

Comment: check this out, https://flutterbyexample.com/lesson/proxy-provider